# Populating UITableView with NSArray in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

A lot of the methods have deprecated in iOS 7 in order to set font, textLabel, and color for UITableView cells. I'm also just having a difficult time populating the view with these values. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSArray* jobs = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

    for(NSDictionary *jobsInfo in jobs) {

        JobInfo *jobby = [[JobInfo alloc] init];
        jobby.city = jobsInfo[@"city"];
        jobby.company = jobsInfo[@"company"];
        jobby.url = jobsInfo[@"url"];
        jobby.title = jobsInfo[@"jobtitle"];
        jobby.snippet = jobsInfo[@"snippet"];
        jobby.state = jobsInfo[@"state"];
        jobby.time = jobsInfo[@"date"];

        jobsArray = [jobsInfo objectForKey:@"results"];
    }
}
```

I am looping through an array of dictionaries from a GET request and parsed. I am now attempting to fill my UITableView with the following code:

-

```
 (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [jobsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *jobsDic = [jobsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[jobsDic objectForKey:@"jobtitle"]];


    return cell;
}
```

Also, I have declared this is in my .h file:

```
NSArray *jobsDic;
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Is this an iOS 7 problem?

Comment: where do you parse the JSON into the viewDidLoad?

Comment: I selected a cell in a tableView and it pushes to another UITableView where a method is then called to parse the data.

Comment: have you checked if the array is already nil into the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you reinitialize jobsarray at the end of the forin loop.

You didn't mean ?

```
NSArray* jobs = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
NSMutableArray *jobsTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:jobs.count];
for(NSDictionary *jobsInfo in jobs) {

    JobInfo *jobby = [[JobInfo alloc] init];
    jobby.city = jobsInfo[@"city"];
    jobby.company = jobsInfo[@"company"];
    jobby.url = jobsInfo[@"url"];
    jobby.title = jobsInfo[@"jobtitle"];
    jobby.snippet = jobsInfo[@"snippet"];
    jobby.state = jobsInfo[@"state"];
    jobby.time = jobsInfo[@"date"];

    [jobsTemp addObject:jobby];
}
self.jobsArray = jobsTemp; //set @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *jobsArray; in the .h
[self.tableView reloadData]; //optional only if the data is loaded after the view
```

In the cell for row method :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    JobInfo *job = self.jobsArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = job.title;

    return cell;
}
```

And don't forget :

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.jobsArray.count;
}
```

Update - an user suggested an edit :

It's true that count isn't a NSArray property. But as Objective-C lets us use a shortcut notation for calling method with a dot, this code works. You have to know limitation of this : if you use a NSArray subclass with a count property with a custom getter this could have side effects `@property (nonatomic, strong, getter=myCustomCount) NSUInteger count`. As I think code readability is to me one of most important things I prefer to use dot notation. I think Apple SHOULD implement count as readonly property so I use it this way (but it's my point of view). So for those which don't agree with me just read `return [self.jobsArray count];` in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration of jobsArray from NSArray to NSMutableArray.

Add an initialization at the beginning point of *fetchedData* method like follows.

```
if(!jobsArray) {
   jobsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}
else {
   [jobsArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

Remove the following line.

```
jobsArray = [jobsInfo objectForKey:@"results"];
```

Instead of that, add the initialized object to the array at the end of for loop.

```
[jobsArray addObject:jobby];
```

Add a *[tableView reloadData];* at the end of your *-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData;* method implementation.

Initially when you are loading the view, tableView will get populated. After you received the data, tableView will not be known that it is received.

Everything else seems good. Hope rest will work fine.